Filtering Data that has already been filtered down to 1 column returns error
I'm having a situation in a Google Sheet where data that has already been filtered down to 1 column is returning an error, even if the next level of filtering is correct.
So, for example, I have 4 rows of data where I'm filtering out columns if there is no value in the qty row.

Then, I'm further filtering that data based on the "Type" row, which generally works just fine. Here is basically an isolated part of my larger formula:
LET(frData, FILTER(rowData, rowQtys <> ""), FILTER(frData, CHOOSEROWS(frData, 3) = "Orange"))
This works just fine when the frData has more than one column in it. The problem is, if frData has been filtered down to one column of data, even though the above filter formula should be true, because CHOOSEROWS(frData, 3) DOES equal "Orange", it is throwing the error  "FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 4. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1."
I've been getting around this by adding a blank column of data to frData so that it is always at least 2 columns wide, but this feels like a hack that I might not remember why I'm doing it if I come back to the formula months from now:
LET(frData, {FILTER(rowData, rowQtys <> ""), {b;b;b;b}},....
Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?
And BTW, what I'm NOT looking for is some IF/ELSE where it says
IF(COLUMNS(frData) = 1, do it a different way, do it the regular way)
That will just bloat my formula.
Thanks!
Here is maybe a better look at how you can recreate what I mean:
In the formula in the image below, change B1:B4 to B1:C4 and it works just fine.

Thanks!!!
EDIT: here is a link to a sheet that has example code
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z6JlNQ0VRNswUWdqAK9Nr5h3oAInd6HCRH7nGAob6EY/edit?gid=0#gid=0

Can you share a spreadsheet with a minimal reproducible example?

@DanielBR here is a sheet I put together that shows the problem https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z6JlNQ0VRNswUWdqAK9Nr5h3oAInd6HCRH7nGAob6EY/edit?gid=0#gid=0


Here's a slight modification you can test:
=LET(allData, transpose(B26:J29), 
     fqData, FILTER(allData, CHOOSEcols(allData, 2) <> ""), 
     transpose(FILTER(fqData, CHOOSEcols(fqData, 3) = "Orange")))


filter() determines which type (vertical or horizontal) filtering to go for based on the conditional true-false array. Obviously this directional factor cannot be determined in this specific scenario since its a single cell conditional value & matching the row count of range & conditional array seems to take precedence



CHOOSEROWS(frData,3) will return only one column and your error message indication that. So, you don't need CHOOSEROWS() function here. Just use-
=LET(frData,B1:B4,FILTER(frData,frData="Orange"))


frData is a 2D range, the filter compare range must be a single row or column. This formula doesn't work.

@ChrisSheeler But you write frData,B1:B4 in you formula.

I sorry! At any rate, check the spreadsheet I posted a link for to see the actual problem. It seems that once you filter a range down to a single column, Google sheets starts treating it as a non 2D array.
